# jQuery.animate - animating really really fast

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework, jquery-animate

```
jQuery('.slide').css('opacity','1').animate({

            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 9999,
            complete: function() {
                this.moveSlideAcross(); // animates a slide across the screen
            }
        });
```

I've set the duration for 9999 and it's animating really really fast. Any ideas how to slow it down?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: script is pretty long. i can't get it to work. I'll try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the second set of braces.

```
jQuery('.slide').css('opacity','1').animate(
    {
        opacity: 0
    },
    9999,
    function() {
        this.moveSlideAcross(); // animates a slide across the screen
    }
);
```

edit: my apologies as this does not work. i dont think i understand jquery as well as i 
should. ill look into it more and fix this answer when i better understand.

edit2: actually this does work :) cheers!

Comment: His method should work, actually... see [this page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). After reading that documentation, I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: As you can see from the [animate API reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) these method signatures are interchangeable.  If you are unhappy with your answer, you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a syntax error. Try this:

```
$('.slide').css('opacity','1').animate(
  {
    opacity: 0,
    left: 0, //your left pos
    top: 0 // your top pos
  },
  9999,
  function() {
    //completion code
  }
);
```

Use top/left in the same declaration as where opacity is to make sure you're not leaving the scope of the animation.

Comment: Where's the syntax error? Your answer actually introduces an IE issue since you added a trailing comma after `top: 0`.

Comment: missed that. fixed. thanks. I guess I didn't mean sytax so much as logic error. He has his animation function running after the animation, which just changed the opacity.